# gem "mail" not decodes base64

Tags: ruby, email, character-encoding

```
require "mail"

Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
                          :port       => 995,
                          :user_name  => 'example@gmail.com',
                          :password   => 'password',
                          :enable_ssl => true
end

email_first = Mail.first
puts email_first.body.decoded
```

It's displays:

> --001a1145b2922bebe405243ff864 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>   KtCyIDE1LjAwLg0KDQoxMSDQvdC+0Y/QsdGA0Y8gMjAxNSDQsy4sIDE0OjUzINC/0L7Qu9GM0LfQ...(many
>   base64)...

Why not decoded to UTF-8?

Comment: This should help http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

Comment: @Ekult3k, Thanks, I read doc. I thought that the gem has a built-in methods. And I found them: https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/encodings.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mail contains a [MIME multipart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) body. That means, the body is composed of multiple parts (which can even potentially be nested), each of which can contain a different object in a different encoding.

Most mails nowadays are sent as multipart messages and can contain e.g. an HTML part and a plaintext part. As the mail gem can't know which parts you want, it gives you an API to enumerate the parts yourself:

```
email_first = Mail.first
puts email_first.parts.first.decoded
```

To find the parts you are most interested in, you can use the stated mimetype in the part, e.g.

```
email_first.parts.first.mime_type
# => text/plain
```